# If $P(x)=p_nx^n+p_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+p_0$ is divided by $x-a$, show that the remainder is $P(a)$. Need help verifying my proof.

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification

> If $P(x)=p_nx^n+p_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+p_0$ is divided by $x-a$, show that the remainder is $P(a)$.

Need help verifying my proof.

Proof: If $P(x)$ is divided by $x-a$, it gives a quotient of $Q(x)$ and remainder $R$.

$P(x)\equiv(x-a)Q(x)+R$

Substituting $a$ for $x$ in this identity gives $R$.

Therefore, $P(a)=(a-a)Q(x)+R \Rightarrow P(a) =R$

Could I please get pointers as to whether this proof is valid?

Comment: Your proof is valid

Comment: This is exactly the same reason for which when $a$ is a root you have $P(a)=0$. Try to see why, Shredalert.

Comment: I would also add that $R$ must be a constant, because the division algorithm forces its degree to be less than the degree of $x-a$, which is $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is valid but somewhat clumsy.

Indeed, you say

"$P(x)\equiv(x-a)Q(x)+R$. Substituting $a$ for $x$ in this identity gives $R$."

followed by

"Therefore, $P(a)=(a-a)Q(\color{red}a)+R \Rightarrow P(a) =R$."

These are essentially the same statements, one is superfluous.

---

By the definition of polynomial division,

$$\forall x:P(x)=(x-a)Q(x)+R,$$ where the constant $R$ is the remainder.

Then

$$P(a)=(a-a)Q(a)+R=R.$$

Comment: I disagree, his proof is clear, in my opinion. Writing $P(x)=(x-a)Q(x)+R$ clearly denotes equality as polynomials, not for some fixed value of $x$...

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: that's right, but then he says "Substituting... ... gives $R$", followed by "Therefore..." where he essentially repeats the same. Of course T is true implies T is true.

Comment: Oh right, I must've read past that. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. Notice only that there should be $P(a)=(a−a)Q(a)+R$ instead of $P(a)=(a−a)Q(x)+R$.

Comment: Why an equivalence symbol ?